# Ambiguity about the exact definition of coefficients of modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

You can see the parts after my questions in the boxes. **I received the answer to my first question in the comments.**

> 1. I am confused about the definition of $a_n$ and $b_n$ in **Part II** below. I know the modular discriminant $\Delta(z) = (2\pi)^{12} \eta(z)^{24}$, and $j$-invariant, $j(z)$, well enough. Is $a_n$ is equal to the coefficient of $q^n$ in $\Delta^n(z)$? I think the author meant something else, and I do not understand what $a_n$ and $b_n$ are.

> 2. Again in **Part II**, how is the relation $f_n(z) = 1 + na_n q^{n+1} + \Big(\frac{nb_n}{2} − 24 n (n + 31)a_n\Big)q^{n+2} + \cdots$ obtained? I'm very curious about that. Can anyone give me a reference for that? This relationship, as the author says, is probably easy to achieve, but I have no idea.

> 3. Regarding **Part I**: According to Hecke-Schoenberg theorem, I know the associated theta series is a modular form of level $N=1$ and trivial character and weight $k=\frac{24n}{2}$. So $f_n \in M_{12n}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$, but why its $q$-development has the form $1+O(q^{n+1})$?

This is from the book "The $1-2-3$ of Modular Forms", pages 35-36 (Chapter 1 "Elliptic Modular Forms and Their Applications" by D. Zagier, Section "Theta Series", Subsection "Invariants of Even Unimodular Lattices"). I just broke it down into different **parts** so that anyone who reads this question can see my problems more easily:

**Theorem (Mallows–Odlyzko–Sloane)**. There are only finitely many nonisomorphic extremal even unimodular lattices.

(**Part I**) We sketch the proof, which, not surprisingly, is completely modular. Since there are only finitely many non-isomorphic even unimodular lattices of any given rank, the theorem is equivalent to saying that there is an absolute bound on the value of the rank m for extremal lattices. For simplicity, let us suppose that $m = 24n$. (The cases $m = 24n+8$ and $m = 24n + 16$ are similar.) The theta series of any extremal unimodular lattice of this rank must be equal to the unique modular form $f_n \in M_{12n}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ whose $q$-development has the form $1+O(q^{n+1})$ (**Why?!?!**).

(**Part II**) By an elementary argument which we omit but which the reader may want to look for, we find that this $q$-development has the form
$$f_n(z) = 1 + na_n q^{n+1} + \Bigg(\frac{nb_n}{2} − 24 n (n + 31)a_n\Bigg)q^{n+2} + \cdots ,$$
**where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the coefficients of $\Delta(z)^n$ in the modular functions $j(z)$ and $j(z)^2$, respectively**, when these are expressed (locally, for small $q$) as Laurent series in the modular form $\Delta(z) = q − 24q^2 + 252q^3 − \cdots$.

(**Part III**, I have neither ambiguity nor curiosity about this part, at least at the moment): It is not hard to show that $a_n$ has the asymptotic behavior $a_n ∼ An^{−3/2}C^n$ for some constants $A = 225153.793389\cdots$ and $C = 1/\Delta(z_0) = 69.1164201716\cdots$, where $z_0 = 0.52352170017992\cdots \times i$ is the unique zero on the imaginary axis of the function $E_2(z)$ defined in (17) (this is because $E_2(z)$ is the logarithmic derivative of $\Delta(z)$), while $b_n$ has a similar expansion but with $A$ replaced by $2\lambda A$ with $\lambda = j(z_0) − 720 = 163067.793145\cdots$. It follows that the coefficient $\frac{1}{2}nbn−24n(n+31)a_n$ of $q^{n+2}$ in $f_n$ is negative for $n$ larger than roughly $6800$, corresponding to $m ≈ 163000$, and that therefore extremal lattices of rank larger than this cannot exist.

Or you can see this image:
[image]

Comment: I think Part I is just the definition of extremal.

For Part II, I think what is meant is to write $$j(z)=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty a_n\Delta(z)^n,\>\>j(z)^2=\sum_{n=-2}^\infty b_n\Delta(z)^n.$$

Comment: @user334725 Regarding **Part I**: In the previous paragraph, the definition of extremal is given as: "*A further consequence of the fact that $\Theta_Q\in M_k(\Gamma_1)$ for $Q$ even and unimodular of rank $m=2k$ is that the minimal value of $Q(x)$ for non-zero $x\in\Lambda$ is bounded by $r= \dim M_k(Γ_1) =[k/12]+1$. The lattice $L$ is called extremal if this bound is attained.*", and I can not see how this definition gives us that condition.

Comment: @user334725 Regarding **Part II**, in which reference did you see the definition of $a_n$ and $b_n$? Also it is my first time that I see these relations: $j(z)=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty a_n\Delta(z)^n,\>\>j(z)^2=\sum_{n=-2}^\infty b_n\Delta(z)^n$, could you please help me to derive these relation or introduce me a book/ note/ link/ ... about that?

Comment: @NeoTheNumberTheoryLover This is just algebra in the field of formal Laurent series $K = \mathbb{C}((q))$: since $\Delta = q+O(q^2)$, for any Laurent series $f \in K$, there exists a unique Laurent series $F$ such that $f = F \circ \Delta$. Indeed, $F$ is equal to $f \circ \Delta^{-1}$ where $\Delta^{-1}$ is the composition inverse of $\Delta$ in $K$, which is well-defined because $\Delta = q + O(q^2)$. This defines $a_n$ and $b_n$ uniquely.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Thank you, this answers my first question.